# Can I use single adjective with auxilary IS

Tags: adjectives

Can I use only one adjective with auxiliary IS?
I/he + am/is + adjective

```
<paragraph>
    <pronounce>I/he</pronounce>
    <auxiliary>am/is</auxiliary>
    <adjective>decided</adjective>
</paragraph>
```

I am decided.

or must I use a phrase for example: "the decided man"?

```
<paragraph>
    <pronounce>I/he</pronounce>
    <auxiliary>am/is</auxiliary>
    <phrase>determinant + adjective + noun</phrase>
</paragraph>
```

Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary 9th edition (eng-eng)
decided BrE /dɪˈsaɪdɪd/ ; NAmE /dɪˈsaɪdɪd/

p.s. могу я писать "я зеленый", или я должен обязательно написать "я есть зеленый человек"

Comment: Questions such as the present one you are putting to the ELU site do not concern this site because they are too basic and are not about the difficulties of the language; those questions are answered on the ELL.  (You can use a single adjective, of course.)

Comment: thx, for You help), I realized I'm going to use another site

Comment: Start with more central adjectives. I am cold / tall / overweight / happy / hungry ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an adjective, known as a subject complement, with “to be” as a main verb.

An auxiliary verb can’t exist without a main verb. If there’s no other verb in your sentence, then “to be” must be a main verb.